# Oracle ASP.net Provider-model objects performance

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, provider

Oracle 11g version of ODP.Net introduces the provider model objects (session state provider, identity provider etc) which lets the application to store these information in an oracle DB without writing custom provider implementation.

Has anyone has done any performance benchmarking on these objects? how do they compare in performance to the sql server implementations provided with .net? I am particularly interested in the performance of the sessionstate provider.

Comment: Sounds interesting, we are still using our own custom provider for personalization data.  I'm interested in the answer too, as we are still using Microsoft's Oracle client in all our projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you download a copy of Reflector and compare the codebases for the SQL Server and Oracle providers (They shouldn't be that complicated.)

I'm going to guess that they're going to look almost identical and perform (from a .NET runtime perspective) similarly.

Whether the Oracle backend is any faster...that's another story.